# Postgresql ERROR: date/time field value out of range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

Hi i am trying to insert a date in my table. But i am getting the error. I also 
tried two solutions which i found:

```
set datestyle to SQL,DMY;

set datestyle = dmy;
```

But the problem still exists. Please help where i am doing mistake. This is the error:

```
Error Number:

ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "24-07-2016" LINE 1: ...isalabad', E'Chief Executive ', E'1994-10-13', E'24-07-20... ^ HINT: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

INSERT INTO "employee" ("fullname", "loginname", "email", "password", "phone", "cnic", "address", "jobdescription", "birthdate", "registered", "qualification", "lastcompany", "lastsalary", "status", "location", "department", "designation", "path") VALUES ( E'Shahzeb Akram', E'shaizi96', E'shaizi@test.com', E'1234', E'3137688894', E'33100-8398084-5', E'Faisalabad, Faisalabad', E'Chief Executive ', E'1994-10-13', E'24-07-2016', E'BSCS', E'BOLT', E'121212', E'1', '', E'39', E'43', E'http://localhost/department/uploads/Shahzeb Akram/Screenshot_(1).png')

Filename: C:/wamp/www/department/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Comment: try using "show datestyle;" to see if your configuration ever made a difference. In any case note that you have one date in the yyyy/mm/dd format so even if you succeed, it will fail on the other one.

Comment: It is showing "ISO, MDY"

Answer (score 2):

I have to change the date format in html input tag to the Postgres date format. Thanks to @Avision for telling me how can i see the current date format used by the Postgres.

I changed it and now it is working fine :)

```
  <input type="text" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" >
```

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. Care to elaborate about what to change where. Where does this line of HTML go and how does it relate to postgres?